# Why session is getting null while inserting the data and getting the data from SQL LITE

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, sqlite

I have written a code to insert the data to `SQL LITE` database as follows

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        count = 0;
       Session["x"] = "session value";

    }
}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string path = Server.MapPath("bin/sampldb.db");
    SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=" + path + "");
    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand();
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        string txt="insert into stu values("+TextBox1.Text  +",'"+TextBox2.Text+"')";
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText  = txt;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close(); 
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Label1.Visible = true;
        Label1.Text = "Error:" + ex.Message;
    }

}
```

After inserting while retrieving data `Session` is getting `null` I don't know why

```
 protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Session["x"] != null) // Getting Null here
    {
        Label1.Visible = true;
        Label1.Text = Session["x"].ToString();
        DataSet m_oDataSet = new DataSet();
        string path = Server.MapPath("bin/sampldb.db");
        SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=" + path + "");
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand();
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            string txt = "select * from stu";
            cmd.CommandText = txt;

            SQLiteDataAdapter adp = new SQLiteDataAdapter();
            adp.SelectCommand = cmd;
            adp.Fill(m_oDataSet);
            GridView1.DataSource = m_oDataSet.Tables[0];
            GridView1.DataBind();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Label1.Visible = true;
            Label1.Text = "Error:" + ex.Message;
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }

    }
}
```

The same code when tested in `Sql server 2008` works fine

```
protected void BtnSqlInsert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cnstr);
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into [User] values ('" + TextBox1.Text + "','" + TextBox2.Text + "')", con);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
}
protected void BtnSqlGet_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Session["x"] != null) //Able to get session here
    {
        Label1.Visible = true;
        Label1.Text = Session["x"].ToString();
    }
}
```

My `sql lite` path is from `Bin` folder as shown in image

[image]

Comment: What do you mean with "is getting null". Is Session equal to null, or is Session["x"] equal to null?

Comment: Means `Session[x]` is `equal to null`

Comment: That's weird, what happens if you set it on PostBack as well. I know that it shouldn't make a difference, but your code looks right.. Are you setting the value to null someplace else..?

Comment: No no the over all code what I have written that I posted. I am not setting `null ` anywhere

Comment: Btw, you should read up on SQL injections. inserting values into a database without sanitizing the input can be disastrous. (What happens if `TextBox2.Text = "1'; drop table stu--`?)

Comment: Hey I know that as in one of my application I am getting this issue so i have designed sample application to know where it is going wrong.

Comment: Given the code you have provided I don't see the problem unfortunately. If you could provide some additional information of what you are doing perhaps it will be easier to spot..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9855/discussion-between-user-and-patrick)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your app writes to DB (which is in BIN folder). That causes app restart => in-proc session gets lost. You should NOT solve the consequence (by using StateServer mode), you should fix the original reason - move db file into another folder, away from BIN folder.